# How to do authentication RichTextEditorComponent image upload to server using serverUrl?

Tags: ej2-syncfusion

```
<RichTextEditorComponent
  name={name}
  id="inlineRTE"
  autoSaveOnIdle
  saveInterval={0}
  ref={ref}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  format={{ width: "auto" }}
  insertImageSettings={{
  saveUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/files/upload'
  }}                        
  </RichTextEditorComponent>
```

saveUrl giving unauthorized error is there any way to pass the custom function to upload image